# Download csv file is not working in safari browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have used the below code to download a csv file

```
let url = "https://test.com/test/auth/files/download/86ccc28c-383f-4c84-ac0d-61478da2f62c/e60f7709-288a-424c-bb13-9ff4bb60bec1?platform=HTMLCLIENT&source=855ca910c9d347b69403cf1791bab97c&linktoken=be50f537833bf693d9e0a3ecb8432159db966ee6"

window.open(url);
```

Above code is working in all browsers except safari browser.

I have done the below work around,

```
let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.target = '_self';
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'test.csv';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
```

which is opening a file in new tab instead of downloading in safari. could any one help with this problem?

Comment: What headers does your server output? Does it include the MIME header?

Comment: if it's iOS Safari, download attribute requires v13.0

Answer (score 1):

Reference: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=167341
https://github.com/dotnetCarpenter/FileReader_Chrome

fetches as blob and converts to a datauri.  Not suitable for large files, as the entire base64 encoded file has to be stored in memory.

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'get',
})
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(blob => {
    const fileName = 'filename.csv'
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE11 and Edge 17-
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName)
    } else { // every other browser
        const reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onloadend = () => {
            const a = document.createElement("a")
            a.href = reader.result
            a.style.display = 'none'
            a.download = fileName
            document.body.appendChild(a)
            a.click()
            a.parentNode.removeChild(a)
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post any of your html? I've had success forcing downloads of files by using the download attribute within an anchor tag.

`<a href="http://www.this.link.com/csv_1.csv" download...`

Comment: First of all thanks for the help and above code won't work for my scenario, i have tried that already. I am dynamically getting "https://test.com/test/auth/files/download/86ccc28c-383f-4c84-ac0d-61478da2f62c/e60f7709-288a-424c-bb13-9ff4bb60bec1?platform=HTMLCLIENT&source=855ca910c9d347b69403cf1791bab97c&linktoken=be50f537833bf693d9e0a3ecb8432159db966ee6"', so that's why i have created dynamic 'a' element.